# binding navigateURL to datagrid

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, datagrid, hyperlink, webforms

I've created a `datagrid` and linked it to one of my tables from my database,
then I want to add a `hyperlink` which should bind to a `column` from the `table`

```
 <asp:DataGrid ID="DataGrid1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
        </asp:DataGrid>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:holidaysConnectionString %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT [Name], [External_Link] FROM [Person]">
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
        <asp:HyperLink ID="hyperlink" runat="server" NavigateUrl='http://www.google.com/<%# Bind("External_Link")%>' Target="_blank">Visit Google</asp:HyperLink>
```

This isn't working can someone advise what I am doing wrong?

I have *2 columns* in my `table`, *`Name` and `External_Hyperlink`*, each row *(inside the `external_hyerplink` column)* contains the extension to a `url` so depending on which row was clicked i would get *`www.google.com/extension1`, or `www.google.com/extension2 etc.`*

But don't think I am in right direction. Please give me some idea to solve my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this as an example:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">           
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ProblemID" />
                <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="ProblemID" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="SmallWindow.aspx?id={0}"
                    DataTextField="Click here" NavigateUrl="SmallWindow.aspx" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Solution" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

**OR**

```
//This event should fire on Row Data Bound

protected void yourGrid_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
        HyperLink hlControl = new HyperLink();
        hlControl.Text = e.Row.Cells[2].Text; //Take back the text (let say you want it in cell of index 2)
        hlControl.NavigateUrl = "http://www.stackoverflow.com";
        e.Row.Cells[2].Controls.Add(hlControl);//index 2 for the example
```

**EDIT**

Try something like this:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink2" runat=server NavigateUrl='<%#Eval("Company_ID", "CompanyProfile.aspx?ID={0}")%>'><%#Eval("Name")%></asp:HyperLink>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, i posted ur code in, it shows up in design view but when I run it i can see nothing, im actually trying to do this using the NavigateUrl='http://www.google.com/<%# Bind("External_Link")%>' feature if you can help?

Comment: Look at my new edit, do something like that and it would work